# Orientdb Update not working within Function

Tags: orientdb, sails-orientdb

I have a function that I call from sails-orientdb which is supposed to update a linkmap on a class. I have tested the function on orient studio and it works fine. However when I call it from sails-orientdb it doesnt update the linkmap.

The orient function is here

```
var gdb = orient.getGraph();
var lastKey = gdb.command("sql","select last(feed.keys()) as lastKey from " + user)[0].getRecord().toMap()["lastKey"];
if(isNaN(parseInt(lastKey)))
 lastKey = 0;

print('\nUser = ' + user);
print('\nItem = ' + item);
print('\nlastKey = ' + lastKey);

var command = "update " + user + " put feed = \"" + (parseInt(lastKey) + 1).toString() + "\" , " + item

print('\ncommand = ' + command);

var results = gdb.command("sql", command);

print('\nresults = ' + results);

return results
```

results above prints out a value of 1

And the sails-orientdb call is here

```
    User.query("select Fan_Out_Write(#26:0 , #12:9)", function (err, result) {

                    if (err) return callback(err, null);

                    return callback(null, result);

        });
```

Any ideas why this is not being committed from sails-orientdb?

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: No exceptions. The values print out on the console where I have orient server running. No exceptions within the nodejs code either.

Comment: From Studio there is the HTTP layer that call the db.commit();
try in your function
gdb.commit();

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From Studio there is the HTTP layer that calls the db.commit();

After the update command you need to commit if calling from external libraries

gdb.commit();